I could use some advice on an appeal
I have what I think is a hot mess on my hands.
I'm just going to lay it out chronologically, I'm not sure how to summarize my issue.
I first attended college over ten years ago. I dropped out after two years. I then attended another college after moving to another state, and dropped out of that after one semester. I then attended an online college and was expelled from that after failing two entire semesters.
Now I am in college again. Overall, I am performing much better than I ever have. I have a passion for something and I'm able to chase it and succeed. However, I have had three courses that I have failed. The first failure was manually adjusted by an instructor after a requirement was missed, another was failed due to a life event, and I now have a third failure where I barely missed a passing grade. The first two I have re-taken and passed.
I now have to appeal to continue going to school where I am at. After reading around online... I think this goes from bad to worse.
When I first started courses at the current school, I sent in transcripts from the first school but neglected the other two since I did not think it was required, and I did not believe anything would transfer. Now I am reading that all transcripts from every college are required. My end game is I want to complete this program and go on with life, and maybe even go further.
I would appreciate any advice on how to proceed. I really want to finish this degree and do something with my life, and do not want to give up. Yes, I screwed up. A lot. Academia is really hard for me but it is something I have to go through to get to where I want to be.
I'll provide other information upon request.

Is there any explicit link that you've been clearly told between your current appeal and the skipped-over transcripts? At first blush, these seems to be unrelated issues.

I am worried that I might be accused of dishonesty or fraud since I did not disclose them thinking it was not required, but now that I re-read the policy... maybe they are?
"If you’ve completed Dual Credit courses or have attended and earned college or military credits prior to your enrollment at [current college], you must have your official college and military transcripts sent to [current college] directly from the issuing college or military. Without those, we cannot grant you credit for previously earned eligible college coursework."
Then again, maybe I'm paranoid.

The passage you quoted doesn't make it sound as if you needed to send them your previous credits. It seems to say that if you want them to count towards your degree they have to be sent directly from the colleges, rather than you sending them a pdf of some marks and pinkie swearing it's real.

Focus on the present appeal and your upcoming courses.
I don't see any reason to think that the missing transcripts are related to that in any way. Nor is it reasonable to think the college has any mechanism to find out about them. I'd suggest you not make further complications or trouble for yourself at this time.
